# How does this while loop condition work?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, while-loop

This function returns a single number after every-other number has been removed. For instance, on the first run, from left to right- 3, 7, and 9 are removed. Then the loop goes on the next iteration from right- to left until finally, just 8 is left.

I don’t understand why only one element (number) is getting pushed to the array. How is this while loop working? Where exactly is the 'filtering taking place? Also, the .reverse function is throwing me off. How does this code know how to go left-to-right, then right-to-left multiple times?

So yeah, any help would be greatly appreciated;-) Thank you

```
function everyOtherfilter(values){
while (values.length > 1){

    new_values = [];
    for (var i=1; i < values.length; i = i+2){
        new_values.push(values[i]);

    }
    values = new_values.reverse();
}

return values[0]

}
(everyOtherFilter([3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 2])) = 8
```

Comment: Why so aggro? Tim squared me away.  Thanks tho;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what actual purpose this function serves, but we can easily run your function with the sample data you provided:

```
3 5 7 8 9 2
  ^   ^   ^    (i = 1, 3, 5)
```

After pushing the selected values (highlighted above) into `new_values` we are left with the following array:

```
5 8 2
```

Now `values` gets assigned the reverse of this array:

```
2 8 5
  ^            (i = 1)
```

During the next iteration of the outer `while` loop, only a single element gets pushed onto `new_values`, which is the value at index 1, the number 8, which also happens to be the center of the array.  So at the end of the second iteration, the `values` array just has one element:

```
8
```

The `while` loop does not iterate again, because the length is just 1 at this point.

Answer (score 0):

```
do{/*statements*/}while(/*condition*/)
```

the do while statement is **do the statement first** then **check your condition if true** it will do the statements again **if false** terminate the loop.

```
while(/*conditions*/){/*statements*/}
```

the while loop **check first the condition if true** do the statements. after doing the statement it will **check the condition again** if false **terminate the loop**

```
   for(/*initialize some index*/;/*condition*/;/*index changes*/){/*statements*/}
```

the for loop **initialize index** then **check the condition** if true **do the statements** then **increment the index** **check condition if false terminate loop**